# Azure DevOps migration using same SQL Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I currently have a TFS 2018 server installation using SQL Server 2017. I'd like to install Azure Devops on a new server but use the same SQL Server.

My plan was to restore the existing Tfs_Configureation and Tfs_Collecton databases as new databases and use them.

However in the installation wizard, I am allowed to pick the configuration database that is to be used but I suspect the collection database will be the current live one.

Is there a support way of altering the collection database inside of the configuration database?

I've found a table called tbl_Database that holds the name and connection strings but am not sure if changing these is enough.

I've found a table called tbl_Database that holds the name and connection strings but am not sure if changing these is enough. I don't want to end up prematurely upgrading the current live collection.

I don't want to end up prematurely upgrading the current live collection and don't want to set up a temporary SQL instance just to test the migration.

Comment: It is **always** recommended to test the migration.

Comment: @DanielMann Thats what I'm trying to do but use the same SQL Server. I might just end up installing dev addition on the test server and have it all self contained.